# Amplifier circuit for Bently Nevada velomitor 330525

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, piezo, vibration

I'm in need of measuring vibrations and I have access to these Bently Nevada velomitors.

I'm not sure how to design a ampliefier circuit for the signal.

The datasheet is says that it is a piezo electric velomitor, but what is throwing me off is that it has power requirements of DC voltage -22 to -30 and bias current of 2,5 to 6 mA. The output bias is -12 +-3 VDC.

The output is 4mV / mm/s and I would like to amplify this by 100, so it would be 400 mV / mm/s. I cannot figure out how to build the circuit because it apparently needs negative volts and it is only a two wire velomitor.

Could someone point me in the right directions? I have dabbled with basic electronics but nothing really with negative volts and piezos.

[Datasheet](https://www.bakerhughesds.com/sites/g/files/cozyhq596/files/2019-08/330525%20Velomitor%20XA%20Piezo-velocity%20Sensor%20Datasheet%20-%20141633.pdf)

Comment: Have you tried searching for this: *Velomitor Sensors User Guide (document 100076)* - as per the recommendations in the data sheet you linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [user guide](https://vdocuments.mx/reader/full/operation-manual-number-100076-01-rev-h-0807-bently-nevada-asset-condition) referenced in the document you linked explains it fairly clearly.

> Traditional velocity sensors consist of either a moving wire coil surrounding a fixed magnet or a fixed wire coil surrounding a moving magnet.  The Velomitor® Sensor is more accurate than traditional velocity sensors.  Because the Velomitor® Sensor contains no moving parts, it is also more durable and less sensitive to transverse motion than traditional seismic transducers. Its piezoelectric sensing element and solid-state circuitry let the Velomitor® Sensor withstand years of continuous use.

> The Velomitor® Sensor **is a two-wire device that requires an external power supply. The power supply must provide a DC voltage of 22 to 30 Volts and a current of 10 mA.** A constant current diode must be used to limit the current to the sensor to 2.5 to 6 mA. Figure 1-1 shows a simple block diagram of the Velomitor® Sensor system. [Emphasis mine.]

Table 3.1 gives the required diode part number:

> 3 mA (Motorola P/N 1N5309) current diode Bently Nevada P/N 00643485.

[image]

*Wiring seems to be as simple as this.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOQRIe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. General gist of your amplifier.*

The datasheet mentions a DC bias on the output so you're going to need to remove that before amplification. C1 does that. You'll need to pick a value that will allow the lowest frequencies of interest through without too much attenuation.

R3 and R4 bias the op-amp to half supply so that your signal can swing symmetrically about that point. You don't say what this is feeding into so I have no idea if this will work in your application.

I had never heard the term before. Thanks for the education.

Comment: Thank you that was extremely helpful. So I can supply it with +24 VDC with the current diode even if it says that it wants -22 to -30 VDC on the datasheet? I'm probably reading it on arduino so I'll modify it to 5V level. Do I need to be conserned about the QA1 input impedance. If so is there anything that you suggest that I would use?

Comment: That's "OA" as in operational-amplifier or op-amp. For most practical purposes the op-amp has infinite input impedance. You'll need a 5 V op-amp with rail-to-rail output in that case to prevent damage to your microcontroller ADC input. I'm not sure what you hope to achieve with this. I don't know that you'll be able to sample at a high enough frequency or do anything useful with the Arduino's limited memory.